# How are Business Hours added to a case?

Tags: businesshours

I am just learning SF and I am noticing that there seems to be no rhyme or reason with what business hours get set on a case.

I opened 8 cases. Two cases Email-to-Case and two through our customer portal for two different accounts. Both accounts have a PT region/entitlement. All of the portal cases had PT Business hours set. Only 1 of the 4 email cases had it set. The rest did not. Confusing!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Business hours gets set through Entitlement Process.**

Verify, if Entitlement Process has been defined at your org and Business hours will be associated with this Entitlement Process. Under this Entitlement Process, there should be milestones defined.

[image: Entitlement Process]

Now, check how Case enters the process. For example, in the screenshot, it is based on created date.

> Entitlement Process is mapped to Entitlement Detail as follows:

[image: Entitlement Details]

**Understanding is**, Entitlement Detail has a Master-Detail relationship to Account. So if you are creating a case upon selecting an account (e.g. test, as per screenshot) that account has entitlement record and based on entitlement record, it will linked to Entitlement Process and from the Entitlement Process, it will return Business hours.

[image: Case to BH]